# How do I get some string values from Pylons controller be assigned to JavaScript variables with Mako?

Tags: python, escaping, pylons, templating, mako

I'm developing under Pylons using Mako templates. The problem is that I need to assign a string from some attribute of tmpl_context to a JavaScript variable in a page body. The additional problem is that this string can be quite arbitrary, ie can contain such characters like ", ', <, >, etc... Is there a common way to do such assignment?
I've tried something like:

```
<script>
    ...
    var a = "${c.my_string}";
    ...
</script>
```

but I get quotation marks and HTML special characters escaped. But I would not like to disable filtering because of possible danger of executing of unexpected code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some arbitrary data in c.my_string, and therefore do not want to use "|n", right?

Quickiest way to escape it in JS-style escaping would be

```
var a = ${c.my_string.__repr__()|n}; # Note lack of "" around it!
```

However I'm unsure about `<>` characters (with something like `</script>` inserted), maybe you would also want to use `.replace('<', '&lt;');`

For unicode you will need to also strip 'u' character from start of the string.

Comment: Right, that seems to be exactly I need. I think the </script> problem is better to solve with .replace('<', '\u003c') because .replace('<', '&lt;') changes the source string.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood what you want, try `webhelpers.html.literal`:

helper:

```
from webhelpers.html import literal
```

html:

```
<script>
    document.write('${h.literal(c.my_string)}');
</script>
```

this is better than `${c.mystring|n}` escaping html

Comment: Not quite that. The aim is assign the value of c.my_string to a JS variable unchanged. For instance, if c.my_string is foo<>_"'"bar then I want some variable `a` to contain exactly foo<>_"'"bar.

Comment: AFAIK literal() does not escape quotes nor does it filter html. So its same as |n - it tells escape() that its content is already escaped.